# while generating csv all values coming in 1 first column

Tags: vb.net, winforms, csv

I am creating csv file from the data reader.my code is like this:

```
 While (dr.Read())

            sw = New StreamWriter(hht_Storage & "\Export\" & strfilename & ".csv", True)
            prcount = 0
            fvalues = ""
            For I = 0 To dr.FieldCount - 1
                If fvalues = "" Then
                    fvalues = IIf(IsDBNull(dr(I)), "", dr(I))
                    fvalues = Trim(Replace(fvalues, "'", ""))
                Else
                    fvalues = fvalues & vbTab
                    fvalues = fvalues & IIf(IsDBNull(dr(I)), "", dr(I))
                    fvalues = Trim(Replace(fvalues, "'", ""))
                End If
            Next I

            sw.WriteLine(fvalues)
            prcount = prcount + 1
            sw.Close()
        End While
```

But all values coming in first column of my CSV.i want to show each values in each of column of csv.
any help is very appreciable.

Comment: I think, it would be a better way to add your field limiter right in front of `Next I`. If you want to have a better performance, then use a StringBuilder instead of fvalues.

Comment: @muffi,in that case how i can re-write my code.

Comment: Using a stringbuilder is optional. It will work with a string as well, no matter. But what is your limiter? I think, it is `vbTab`, right? In this case, move this line down right in front of `Next`: `fvalues = fvalues & vbTab`

Comment: fvalues = fvalues & vbTab
            Next I  i given code like this,but still coming old format

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

The data reader classes implement the `IEnumerable` interface, which means that you can call the `Cast` extension method to get an `IEnumerable(Of Object)`, which is a type that the `String.Join` method accepts:

```
Using writer As New StreamWriter("file path here")
    While myDataReader.Read()
        writer.WriteLine(String.Join(ControlChars.Tab, myDataReader.Cast(Of Object)()))
    End While
End Using
```

If you need to process each item then you can simply add a `Select` call:

```
Using writer As New StreamWriter("file path here")
    While myDataReader.Read()
        writer.WriteLine(String.Join(ControlChars.Tab,
                                     myDataReader.Cast(Of Object)().
                                                  Select(Function(o) o.ToString().
                                                                       Trim().
                                                                       Replace("'",
                                                                               String.Empty))))
    End While
End Using
```

That's now passing am `IEnumerable(Of String)` to `String.Join` but the other overload simply calls `ToString` on each item anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (change the limiter to vbTab if you wish to):

```
    Dim sb As New Text.StringBuilder
    sw = New StreamWriter(hht_Storage & "\Export\" & strfilename & ".csv", True)
    prcount = 0
    While (dr.Read())
        sb.Clear()
        For I As Integer = 0 To dr.FieldCount - 1
            If IsDBNull(dr(I)) = False Then sb.Append(dr(I).ToString)
            sb.Append(";") 'Field limiter
        Next I
        sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString)
        prcount = prcount + 1
    End While
    sw.Close()
```